# print() command does not contain all expected values

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I am reading data from .csv data and want to write parts of that data into an output file.
When I execute the program and print the results, I get the complete  data set of the input file.
However, when I hit print() again, only the last line of the input file is shown.

When I write the print-result into another csv file, as well only the last line is transfered

Basically I am new at this and struggle to understand how data is stored in cache and passed on.

```
import csv
with open("path to the input file") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    for line in file:
        input_data = line.strip().split(";")
        print(input_data)

with open(os.path.join("path to the output file"), "w") as file1:
                    toFile = input_data
                    file1.write(str(toFile))
```

There is no error messages, just not the expected result. I expect 10 lines to be transferred, but only the last makes it to the output .csv

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Inside loop, `input_data` is overridden in every iteration which ultimately results in it holding only the last line.

Answer (score 0):

When you loop over the lines in the csv each iteration you assign the value of that line to input data, overwriting the value previously stored in `input_data`.

I would recommend something like the following:

```py
import csv
with open('path to input file', 'r') as input, open('path to output file', 'w') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(input)
        for line in reader:
            ouput.write(line.strip().split(';'))
```

you can open multiple files in a single with clause like I showed in the example. Then for each line in the file you write the stripped and split string to the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it. You created the reader object correctly but didn't use it. I hope my example will better your understanding of the reader class.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import csv
from os import linesep

def write_csv_to_file(csv_file_name, out_file_name):

    # Open the csv-file
    with open(csv_file_name, newline='') as csvfile:

        # Create a reader object, pass it the csv-file and tell it how to 
        # split up values
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')

        # Open the output file
        with open(out_file_name, "w") as out_file:

            # Loop through the rows that the reader found
            for row in reader:

                # Join the row values using a comma as separator
                r = ', '.join(row)

                # Print row and write to output file
                print(r)
                out_file.write(r + linesep)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    csv_file = "example.csv"
    out_file = "out.txt"
    write_csv_to_file(csv_file, out_file)
```